# Enabled button in a form through access control

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get access to parent control from user control - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820606/get-access-to-parent-control-from-user-control-c-sharp)

I have `btnMessage` on my form `Main`, and I also have user control (`uc`).

When I click `btnMessage`, it opens the `uc` and also makes `btnMessage.enabled = false`. In `uc`, there's a button that's called `btnExecute`.

What I want is that when I click on `btnExecute` in `uc`, `btnMessage` in `Main` form will be disabled. How I can do this?

Here's the update code :

I'm using function in `main.cs`

```
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        formFunctionPointer += new functioncall(buttonHideorEnabled);
        ucMessageTarget.userFunctionPointer = formFunctionPointer;
    }

    public delegate void functioncall(bool _status);

    private event functioncall formFunctionPointer;

    public void buttonHideorEnabled(bool _status)
    {
        btnMessageTarget.Enabled = _status;
    }
```

and in `uc.cs` :

```
    public static string agentName = UtilitiesToolkit.agentMessageTarget;
    public static string strn;

    public UcMessageTarget(string str)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        strn = str;
    }

    public Delegate userControlPointer;
    public Delegate userFunctionPointer;
    private void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       btnExecute.enabled = false;
       userFunctionPointer.DynamicInvoke(false);
       //I want btnMessage in Main form also disabled, please tell me how
    }
```

but, still, didn't work. when I compile, I have error in main, in this line :

```
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        formFunctionPointer += new functioncall(buttonHideorEnabled);
        ucMessageTarget.userFunctionPointer = formFunctionPointer;
    }
```

said, that

> *object reference is not set to an instance of object (in
>   ucMessageTarget.userFunctionPointer = formFunctionPointer;).*

please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically subscribe to event handlers in the code-behind, so add one to the "parent" form for the "child" form's button:

```
uc.btnExecute.Click += new EventHandler(name_of_method_to_handle_click_event);
```

The only requirement is that the control be `public` so that the parent form can access it.

Comment: how i can make btnMessage enabled = false when I click btnExecute in uc?

Answer (score 0):

What I would rather do is raise an event from the user control, which the main form listens to, and then disable the button in this event handler.

Something like [User Control Events in VB and C#](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/07/22/user-control-events-in-vb-and-c.aspx)

This would avoid the user control having to "know" anything about the caller (parent form).

Search a little on SO, you will find a lot of examples for raising events from user controls.

Comment: how i can make btnMessage enabled = false when I click btnExecute in uc?