# Move Event for Parent Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on adding some functionality and fixing some bugs in this code I found here:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/a644fc/multicolumn-combobox-with-configurable-display-and-value-members-and-fast-search-functionality/

One issue is that the grid attached to the textbox stays in the same position on the screen when you move the window.  I'm trying to fix this by hiding the grid whenever the parent form is moved. In the MultiColumnComboBox class file, I'm using this line of code

```
 this.Parent.Move += new System.EventHandler(this.parent_Move);
```

to add my function, parent_Move in the parent's move event.  The issue is that Parent is always null.  Is there any way to add to the parent's move event from the class file? Or is there any other way to determine if the parent form's screen location changed?  I'm planning on using this control a lot and would prefer to find a way to fix the issue in the class rather than in each file where I would call it.  Thank you guys for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `this.Parent` is always null, perhaps this answer would be of help to you: [Get access to parent control from user control - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8820648/1899147)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I was able to get it by changing the constructor to accept a parent form and creating a class property ParentForm to be set to that form.  So now, when the parent form is moved, it triggers my new parent_Move function.  Thank you!