# Access control in MainForm from UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to access a control (user control and just normal control) located on the MainForm from within a UserControl that was added to the MainForm.

I have tried:

```
(this.Parent as Form).viewport.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

and also:

```
Form1.viewport.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

and I've also set Modifier property on both controls that I need to access on the MainForm to: `Public`, but I am still unable to access these controls.

How can a UserControl access it's Parent's controls in code/runtime?

Comment: `viewport` is not a member of `Form`, it is a member of your derived form class. I suppose that's `Form1`. And I highly recommend checking for errors, rather than just assuming the code will work and letting it blow up if it doesn't.

Comment: The first method will fail because `Form` does not have a member called `viewport`.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok. I'm just having a braindead moment, I figured it out:

```
(this.Parent as Form).Controls["TabStripContainer"].Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code which is on the below:

[Get access to parent control from user control - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820606/get-access-to-parent-control-from-user-control-c-sharp)

MyForm

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
   public MyForm()
   {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.myUserControl1.ParentForm = this;
   }
}
```

MyUserControl

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
   public MyForm ParentForm { get; set; }

public MyUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ParentForm == null)
        return;

    ListBox listBox = (ParentForm.Controls["listBox1"] as ListBox);
    listBox.Items.Add("Test");

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tested this and works fine

```
((this.Parent) as Form2).uc2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

where form2 is the form that contains the user control uc2.