# javascript bounded cant change form object visible false

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

I changed cefsharp winforms example.

it bound callback.
 browser.RegisterJsObject("bound", new BrowserForm());
it bound BrowserForm to can access from java to call AddTab from java

I successfully called c# methods from javascript via bound.

my problem is I cant hide image object when calling from java.
but with button on form we can do.

c# code

```
public void Load_successfull()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("working good.");
        loading_animation.Visible = false;

    }
```

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Load_successfull();
        }

java code:
bound.load_successfull();

when called from java cant hide loading_animation

Comment: You need to marshal your calls back onto the UI thread. E.g BeginInvoke

Comment: can you send full example or complete my code above?

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for details

Comment: I changed to this code. by click button worked but from java bound call bound.load_successful no hide object               public delegate void InvokeDelegate();

        public void Load_successfull()
        {
            loading_animation.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(hide_animation));
        }


        public void hide_animation()
        {
            loading_animation.Visible = false;
MessageBox.Show("called ok");
        }

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: Looking at your original code again, you need to pass in the current instance of the form, not create a new one. should be `browser.RegisterJsObject("bound", this);`

Comment: loading_animation.Visible = false not worked when called by java bound callback. or when runed by timer interval. just worked by click button call

Comment: Fact that it doesn't work by timer should tell you something. Anyway, the problem isn't `CefSharp` related. You'll need to read up on `WinForms Threading`, particularly `BeginInvoke`. I'm sure `StackOverflow` has plenty of questions that already cover the topic.

Comment: hi again. thanks for spend time. I call from c# timer it worked and hide. but from cefsharp winform.example can not. because of browser.RegisterJsObject are in class BrowserTabUserControl I cant use this for bound. all methods are in BrowseForm and lables are in it. then I forced to use new BrowserForm() .

Comment: Passing in a reference to `new BrowserForm()` is not the same as passing in a reference to the already running instance of `BrowerForm`, do you understand that? Use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample as the basis of your testing, it's much simpler.

Comment: thanks. how I can change active form lables and images position and visibility from other class? if re new BrowserForm is not good method ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820606/get-access-to-parent-control-from-user-control-c-sharp If your new to `WinForms` or `.Net` then I suggest you start reading some tutorials, get a better understand for the framework.