# C# UserControl Nested in TabControl, accessTabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

So I am making a small Program where I have a UserControl inside a tab control. And i am trying to find out how to go back up a level from inside the user control to add tabs to the tab control.

Comment: is this winform or wpf?

Comment: This should help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820606/get-access-to-parent-control-from-user-control-c-sharp

Comment: Just don't, a control should never monkey with its container.  Raise an event instead, the form can take care of it.

Answer (score -1):

Okay Thanks for the comment, I figured it out, the link posted by CarbineCoder had the following code

```
Form parentForm = (this.Parent as Form);
```

This is the code i was trying to use but what was actually needed was

```
Form parentForm = (this.Parent.Parent as Form);
```

Comment: Well, that makes no sense.  The Parent of the user control is the TabPage.  The parent of the tab page is the TabControl.  That's not a Form.  Don't do this at all, it is wrong.

Comment: I wanted the TabControl though? I was aiming to get the TabControl